# Error adding new namespace in symfony2

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces

I'm developing an application using Symfony2 and Doctrine 2.

Technical Specs

I'm using Symfony 2.7.1

I'm using PostgreSQl 1.18.1

I'm trying to add a cast function using package called oro-crm doctrine extensions. I have that in app/config/config.yml:

```
dql:

                datetime_functions:
                    date:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    time:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    timestamp:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    convert_tz:     Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\DateTime\ConvertTz
                numeric_functions:
                    timestampdiff:  Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\TimestampDiff
                    dayofyear:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    dayofmonth:     Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    dayofweek:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    week:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    day:            Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    hour:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    minute:         Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    month:          Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    quarter:        Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    second:         Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    year:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
                    sign:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\Sign
                    pow:            Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\Pow
                string_functions:
                    group_concat:   Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\String\GroupConcat
                    concat_ws:      Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\String\ConcatWs
                    cast:           Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Cast
```

This is the namespace of /oro/doctrine-extensions/src/Oro/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/Cast.php:

namespace Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions;

I have that in symfony2 composer.json

```
"oro/doctrine-extensions":"dev-master"
```

Well, the problem is that when I'm trying to add the configuration to Doctrine with this command:

```
$config=$this->em->getConfiguration();
$config->addCustomStringFunction('CAST', 'Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Cast');
```

I got that error:

`Attempted to load class "Cast" from namespace "Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

Comment: Can you add the /oro/doctrine-extensions/src/Oro/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/Cast.php file?

Comment: Is your posted config.yml cut off on the first few lines? https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions#symfony2 prepends more lines that make more sense (don't know SF2 but this could be a problem)

Comment: Here is the pastebin with the cast class: http://pastebin.com/g2W4MuDs

Comment: The config.yml is cut off because I wanted to show only the dql part but the file has more lines

Comment: Check the docs on how to add dql functions to doctrine.  The dql portion of config.yml will take care of that for you.  No need to explicitly call addCustomStringFunction.  But the dql section you posted is all messed up.   http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: And remove your name_spaces_autoload edit.  That ain't right either.  composer update will generate the necessary autoload lines.